# get result from async task class cause not responding

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

I wrote a class that extend async task; i send data to it and class return  a json object

But on pre-execute function on async task not working and my program go in not responding mode until class finish its job

```
public class async_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>
{
    Context mycontext;
    List<NameValuePair> query_List=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String  str_URL;

    ProgressDialog  progressDialog;
    JSONObject      jsonObject      =null;
    JSONParser      jsonParser      =new JSONParser();

    public async_Task(Context context,List<NameValuePair> lst_NameValuePairs,String url_String)
    {
        this.mycontext  =context;
        this.query_List =lst_NameValuePairs;
        this.str_URL    =url_String;

        progressDialog  =new ProgressDialog(mycontext, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("wait please...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            jsonObject=jsonParser.store_And_Feedback(str_URL, query_List);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                jsonObject.put("res_code", "-5");
                jsonObject.put("res", e.getMessage());

            }
            catch (JSONException e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject args)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

and i called async task in my activity

```
jsonObject=new async_Task(JAct_Singup.this, lst_NameValuePairs, str_Url).execute().get();
```

i need to get result(jsonobject) form async task and when remove get(); i give this error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject> to JSONObject
```

Comment: what you are using `get()` method ?

Comment: Dont call AsynchTask get() method it will block your UI thread

Comment: i need to get jsonobject from async task for another proccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found solutions

1- create new `interface` class

```
public interface AsyncResponse
{
    void progressEnd(JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

2- declare class in async task class

```
public class async_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>
{
    public AsyncResponse response   =null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
         ....
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        ...
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject args)
    {
        ...
        response.progressEnd(jsonObject);
    }

}
```

3- implements class or activity from created `interface` class(AsyncResponse)

```
public class JAct_Singup extends Activity implements AsyncResponse
{
    .........
    @Override
    public void progressEnd(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```

each time you call async task class the `progressEnd` called after finish async task

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in your store_And_Feedback(str_URL, query_List) method ..

Debug it line by line code of store_And_Feedback(str_URL, query_List) method.

or Post here so that i can to review this

Comment: this class work correct; my problem is when i run app activity go in not responding status; after of efew sec i see the result

Comment: whatever you are doing in store_And_Feedback(str_URL, quary_List) ..just write that code in doInbackground() method. this works for me.